# Рендер ошибки из плагина redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, плагин, redmine

Как отправить на рендер свое сообщение из хука контроллера?
что-то вроде flash[:error] = "Message". <- С данным методом не работает, падает редмайн с 500.

Хук

```
module Integration
  class ControllerIssuesNewBeforeSaveHook < Redmine::Hook::ViewListener
    def controller_issues_new_before_save(context={})
      # Получаем данные из формы
      project_id = context[:issue].project.custom_field_values[0].value.to_i
      if (project_id == 0 || project_id.blank?)
        flash[:error] = "Error" # Пока всё упадет с 500
        redirect_to :back
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Ошибка

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method flash' for #<Integration::ControllerIssuesNewBeforeSaveHook:0x0000000410b298>):
  plugins/integration/lib/integration/controller_issues_new_before_save_hook.rb:16:incontroller_issues_new_before_save' lib/redmine/hook.rb:61:in block (2 levels) in call_hook'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:61:ineach' lib/redmine/hook.rb:61:in block in call_hook'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:58:intap' lib/redmine/hook.rb:58:in call_hook'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:91:incall_hook' app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:139:in create'
  lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:63:insudo_mode'
```

Comment: Не работал с Redmine, но что если вместо `flash` использовать `context[:flash]`?

Comment: соврал.

выдвает ошибку

NoMethodError (undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass):


находил подобный вариант:

context[:controller].flash[:notice] << 'something to append to the flash message'

но в этом случае кидает:

NoMethodError (undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass):

Comment: Ну, это уже прогресс, там даже объект флэша есть. Попробуйте зацепиться туда отладчиком и посмотрите, что там за объект. Возможно, `["notice"]` вместо `[:notice]` надо?

Answer (score 0):

Вы не с того конца заходите, запатчите модель Issue и вынесите вашу проверку в валидацию. Ваша ошибка выведется стандартным error_messages_for в redmine